# Key step in a proof involving complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

This question is within the context of Cauchy-Riemann equations.
The text I am reading lists a theorem regarding the existence of the derivative of a function $f$ at point $z_0$. My question concerns a step in the proof of the theorem.

---

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) $

> $\triangle{z}=\triangle{x}+i\triangle{y} $  ;
> $0<\lvert\triangle{z}\rvert<\epsilon$;  $\triangle{w}=f(z_0+\triangle{z})-f(z_0)$

where $\triangle{u}=u(x_0+\triangle{x},y_0+\triangle{y})-u(x_0,y_0)$.

---

The proof states that if the first order partial derivative of $u$ is continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, it follows that $\triangle{u}=u_x(x_0,y_0)\triangle{x}+u_y(x_0,y_0)\triangle{y}+\epsilon_1\triangle{x}+\epsilon_2\triangle{y}$.

Note: $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0$ as $(\triangle{x},\triangle{y}) \to (0,0) $

I do not understand how the previous result follows from the condition given. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate NIcNic8?

Comment: Can you provide the complete proof?

Comment: I already found a solution NicNic8, if you are interested it's P88 onwards file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/Advanced_Calculus_Fifth_Edition_Wifred_K.pdf